# onClick not taking effect on tr

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am coding with React.
Can anyone tell me why my `onClick` on my `<tr>` does not take effect when I click on the row?

```
  return (
    <tr
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("clicked");
      }}
    >
      ...
    </tr>
  );
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. I think the problem might be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: please add more infos and best a link to a codesandbox, we cannot see what else is happening. here is an example of your code and its working: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-feistel-w9p7x?file=/src/App.js:67-78

Comment: Also avoid adding onclick on random html elements, use buttons for this kind of behaviour if possible.

Comment: It works, check: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-bed-react-code-forked-ysbks?file=/index.js

Comment: You guys are right: There is something else in my code that causes it: An z-index, that makes my div behind another div. 
Thank you for advices!